# Rotation restarts activity

Tags: android

I have a problem with my android app. My activities restart when I rotate my phone (onCreate is called). I have googlet and have tried 
`android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation">` in my manifes, but with no luck. Can someone please explain to me how I can get this to work

**EDIT:** I find out that i nedd to ad these codes

**manifest**

```
<activity
    android:name="?"
    android:label="@string/?"
    android:theme="@style/?" 
    android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
```

**MainActivity**

```
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    // Checks the orientation of the screen
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
        Toast.makeText(this, "portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: you can reload the data accordingly on rotate, or lock it to portrait | landscape.

Comment: How can i reload the data on rotate?

Comment: Restarting your activity on configuration change is the correct & natural behavior on Android. Just use onSaveInstanceState to save the data that you want to keep during rotations.

Answer (score 2):

In your Activity, you can override the method `onSaveInstanceState`. You can save the information you need into a `Bundle`. That bundle will be passed in to the `onCreate` method after the orientation has changed. If you would rather just specify one orientation to be used, within your manifest file, either under the application tab or activity tag, place:

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try `android:configChanges="keyboard|orientation|screenSize">`. However, be aware that restarting the Activity on configuration change is normal behavior. Unless you have very specific needs, you should not be using configChanges.